# Is there a way to run MATLAB functions in Excel?

Tags: matlab, vba, excel

I wrote some MATLAB functions that read data from an Excel sheet, perform calculations, and write the results in the same Excel sheet.

Is there a possibility to use these MATLAB functions directly in Excel, without MATLAB?

For instance, is it possible to convert MATLAB code to VBA code? Or is it possible to add it as a macro button in some way?

Comment: You can most likely manually convert it. If you are asking us to find a library / program that converts it automatically then this question if off topic. You maybe able to reference matlab and use the functions in there but you will have to look up if you can.

Comment: Have you [Googled around](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Matlab+to+VBA+converter)? I found some sites, such as [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) that seems to have some options. You may have to pay for some of them though.  From what I've seen, there's isn't something that's essentially copy/paste, but will require some work on your end.